# Stripping data out of a string in Vbscript

Tags: asp-classic, vbscript

I currently have a variable called databaseinformation in a script that I am writing. I want to seperate this into two variables called Instance_Name and Database_Name

The string in question:

[MSSQLSERVER]BESMgmt.BAK

In this instance the Instance_Name is MSSQLSERVER and the Database_Name is BESMgmt. The string will not necessarily end in .BAK but stripping the last four characters off the variable would be fine. The Instance_Name and Database_Name will change values and length.

Thanks for any help in advance

Comment: Are you still coding in VBScript and old ASP in 2011 !?!?!?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Or do it with a regular expression object, this makes you more flexible, allthough some will say that you have two problems now:

```
Option Explicit
Dim regEx, matches
Dim myString : myString = "[MSSQLSERVER]BESMgmt.BAK"

set regEx = new RegExp
regEx.pattern = "\[(.*)\](.*).{4}"

set matches = regEx.Execute(myString)
msgbox "Instance_name: " & matches(0).subMatches(0) & vbNewLine & "Database_name: " & matches(0).subMatches(1)
```

Answer (score 2):

@Trinitrotoluene: Working sample code --

```
Option Explicit

Dim ToBeSplit, Instance_Name, Database_Name
Dim SplitMe
Dim Position

ToBeSplit = "[MSSQLSERVER]BESMgmt.BAK"

SplitMe = Split(ToBeSplit, "]")

If IsArray(SplitMe) Then
    Instance_Name = SplitMe(0)
    Database_Name = SplitMe(1)
End If

Instance_Name = Replace(Instance_Name, "[", "")

If InStr(Database_Name, ".") > 0 Then 
    Database_Name = Left(Database_Name, Len(Database_Name) - 4)
End If

Response.Write "Instance_Name = " & Instance_Name & "<br>"
Response.Write "Database_Name = " & Database_Name
```